# Expand ListView with animation onUpdate data

Tags: android, listview

I've got a `ListView` with some items. I know it's height. Sometimes I get an event to update this `ListView`, which changes the content of items changing their height. I can calculate new height. How can I create animation to update this `ListView` from old height to new height?

I didn't add new items. I just changed current items(added some new `TextView` for current `ViewHolder`).

Also, I can show expand animation from 0 to desired height, but what I need is an animation from one height to another. Are there any solutions?

Thank you!

Comment: So many negative votes and no comments so he can improve his question...

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView is the better option for you. It includes default animation while adding or removing items.
A sample could be found here,
http://android-er.blogspot.in/2015/07/add-and-remove-items-to-recyclerview.html

Comment: I didn't add new items. I just changed current items(added some new textViews for current ViewHolder).